# Implement multiple types of back-end dynamic filters using Django QuerySets in ListView

Tags: jquery, django, listview, filter

I am trying to display a specific set of objects in my models in a ListView, and I need to construct a queryset with the appropriate filters. I am trying to filter protocols by its technology types, object types and subjects. These three filters are all tree-structured, therefore I imported the MPTTModel.

In models.py, I have these models:

```
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel

class BPSubject(MPTTModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    engname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    scopenote = models.TextField(blank = True)
    annotation = models.TextField(blank=True)

class BPTechnoType(MPTTModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    engname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)

class BPObjectType(MPTTModel, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    engname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',null=True, blank=True, related_name='children', db_index=True)
    bptechno = models.ManyToManyField(BPTechnoType, blank=True) 

class Bioprotocol(models.Model):
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        TechnoType = models.ManyToManyField(BPTechnoType)
        ObjectType = models.ManyToManyField(BPObjectType)
        Abstract = models.TextField(blank=True)
        Subject = models.ManyToManyField(BPSubject)
```

Then I defined a view for my index page showing all the categories(Subject,ObjectType and TechnoType):

In views.py:

```
class BPCategoryList(ListView):
    model = BPSubject
    context_object_name = "bpsubject_list"
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BPCategoryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bpobjecttype_list'] = BPObjectType.objects.all()
        context['bptechnotype_list'] = BPTechnoType.objects.all()
        context['bioprotocol_list'] = Bioprotocol.objects.all()

        return context
```

Then hook that view into my urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                      url(r'^index/', BPCategoryList.as_view()),
)
```

The template for index.html is as below:

Notes： In MPTT Model, it automatically generates a 'Level' field indicating the level of the object in the tree structure, and I assigned the category name like 'Technology Type'/'Object Type'/'Subject' on the level 0.

```
<div id="container">
            <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="mainNavs">
                    <div class="menu_box">
                    {% for bptechnotype in bptechnotype_list %} 
                    {% if bptechnotype.level = 0 %} <!-- The Level 0 of the MPTT Model  -->
                    <div class="menu_main">
                        <h2>{{ bptechnotype.name }}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_sub dn">
                    {% elif bptechnotype.level = 1 %}
                        <dl class="reset">
                            <dt><a href="/bptechnotype/{{ bptechnotype.name }}">{{ bptechnotype.name }}</a></dt>
                            <dd>
                                {% for children in bptechnotype.get_children %}
                                <a href="/bptechnotype/{{ children.name }}">{{ children.name }}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_box">
                    {% for bpobjecttype in bpobjecttype_list %}
                    {% if bpobjecttype.level = 0 %}
                    <div class="menu_main">
                        <h2>{{ bpobjecttype.name }}</h2>

                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_sub dn">
                    {% elif bpobjecttype.level = 1 %}
                        <dl class="reset">
                            <dt><a href="/bpobjecttype/{{ bpobjecttype.name }}">{{ bpobjecttype.name }}</a></dt>
                            <dd>
                                {% for children in bpobjecttype.get_children %}
                                <a href="/bpobjecttype/{{ children.name }}">{{ children.name }}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_box">
                    {% for bpsubject in bpsubject_list %}
                    {% if bpsubject.level = 0 %}
                    <div class="menu_main">
                        <h2>{{ bpsubject.name }}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu_sub dn">
                    {% elif bpsubject.level = 1 %}
                        <dl class="reset">
                            <dt><a href="/bpsubject/{{ bpsubject.name }}">{{ bpsubject.name }}</a></dt>
                            <dd>
                                {% for children in bpsubject.get_children %}
                                <a href="/bpsubject/{{ children.name }}">{{ children.name }}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </dd>
                        </dl>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The above scripts work very well.However, I can only use one type of filter per time to get the corresponding protocols. But I want to do more after I get the above results. I want that the next page, with the ListView that enables users to be able to narrow down their selection, for example, only some of the protocols in this objecttype with some specific subjects. Thus I want to construct filters based on each of these three categories. I add three more ListViews in my views.py, here I just pick one of them (the BPTechnoTypeBioprotocolList) to present the problem:

```
class BPTechnoTypeBioprotocolList(ListView): 
    template_name = 'bioprotocol_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.technotype = get_object_or_404(BPTechnoType, name=self.args[0])
        bptechnotype_list = Bioprotocol.objects.filter(TechnoType__lft__gte=self.technotype.lft, TechnoType__rght__lte=self.technotype.rght)
        return bptechnotype_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BPTechnoTypeBioprotocolList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        bpobjecttype_list = []
        bptechnotype_list = []
        bpsubject_list = []
        for item in self.get_queryset():
            bpobjecttype = BPObjectType.objects.filter(bioprotocol__id=item.id)
            bpsubject = BPSubject.objects.filter(bioprotocol__id=item.id)
            bptechnotype = BPTechnoType.objects.filter(bioprotocol__id=item.id)
            bpobjecttype_list += bpobjecttype
            bpsubject_list += bpsubject
            bptechnotype_list += bptechnotype
        objecttypecount = Counter(bpobjecttype_list).most_common()
        technotypecount = Counter(bptechnotype_list).most_common()
        subjectcount = Counter(bpsubject_list).most_common()            
        # Add in the subject
        context['bpobjecttype_list'] = objecttypecount
        context['bptechnotype_list'] = technotypecount
        context['bpsubject_list'] = subjectcount
        context['bptechnotype'] = self.technotype
        return context
```

and in my urls.py I add:

```
url(r'^bptechnotype/([\w-]+)/$', BPTechnoTypeBioprotocolList.as_view()),
```

The template of bioprotocol_list.html is:

```
<div class="sidebar">
                <div id="options" class="greybg">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            "Object Type"
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            {% for objecttype in bpobjecttype_list %}
                            <div class="option">
                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="">{{ objecttype.0 }}</label> ({{ objecttype.1 }})
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            "Technology Type"
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            {% for technotype in bptechnotype_list %}
                            <div class="option">
                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="">{{ technotype.0 }}</label> ({{ technotype.1 }})
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <dl>
                        <dt>
                            "Subject"
                        </dt>
                        <dd>
                            {% for subject in bpsubject_list %}
                            <div class="option">
                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="" value="">{{ subject.0 }}</label> ({{ subject.1 }})
                            </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                    <button type="button" id="selectall">Select All</button>
                    <button type="button" id="cancelall">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="applyfilter">Filter</button>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#selectall").click(function(){
                                $("input").prop('checked', true)
                            });
                            $("#cancelall").click(function(){
                                $("input").prop('checked',false)
                            });
                            $("#applyfilter").click(function(){
                                SHOULD DO SOMETHING AND SEND THE QUERYSET TO THE LISTVIEW
                                });
                            });
                        })
                    </script>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

The main idea is to apply a jQuery function ($("#applyfilter").click(function(){}) to loop through each checkbox input, and get all the checked filter and send the request to ListView and change the get_queryset()

The scripts must contain some duplicated codes. I am looking forward to some concise methods to make dynamic list of objects with filters of these three categories on one page.Any ideas appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix on my own by adding the codes to

```
function getvalue(){
                            var objectchk = [];
                            var technochk = [];
                            var subjectchk = [];

                            $("input[name='objecttype']:checked").each(function(){
                                objectchk.push($(this).val());
                            });

                            $("input[name='technotype']:checked").each(function(){
                                technochk.push($(this).val());
                            });

                            $("input[name='subject']:checked").each(function(){
                                subjectchk.push($(this).val());
                            });

                            var dict = {
                                'ObjectType':objectchk, 'TechnoType':technochk, 'Subject':subjectchk
                            };

                            var params = $.param(dict);

                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                data: {'ObjectType':objectchk, 'TechnoType':technochk, 'Subject':subjectchk},
                            });

                            window.location = "?" + params
                        }
```